# How can I debug typescript in Yarn2 workspace using vscode?

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, vscode-debugger, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

I have yarn2 (berry) project with workspaces and I'm using ts-node to run each workspace (package). How do I set up the vscode launch.json to be be able to debug a workspace? For clarification, I have a global tsconfig with general configuration and individual tsconfig inside each worksapce extending the global tsconfig to specify the input/output directory for each package.

I tried to play around with the launch.json configuration for nodejs but all my tries are failing. Setting the runtimeExecutable to "yarn" and tried different runtimeArgs values.

Comment: If you run the transpiled code, does it run using `node` or does it run in a browser?

Comment: I'm running it the project as node without browser